# Laravel upload .heic image

Tags: laravel, file-upload, heic

I have added **Imagick** library and tried to upload .heic image

```
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->readImage($request->image);
```

And always return this error

> NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `HEIC' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing works.

phpinfo
[image]

Comment: It shows you do not have HEIC format supported as a format. Did you install it with HEIC support? See https://medium.com/@eplt/5-minutes-to-install-imagemagick-with-heic-support-on-ubuntu-18-04-digitalocean-fe2d09dcef1

Comment: I tried this tutorial but the result as u shown above, the HEIC not added

Comment: Unless you are experiencing some error message in the install, I don't think you will be able to find help here. The issue here is with your installation.

Comment: And you have definitely restarted your apache/nginx?

Comment: I restarted my Nginx and nothing happened, Also I didn't experience any error in the install, anyway, how can I reinstall this library?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding [this](http://stuffjasondoes.com/2019/07/10/batch-convert-heic-to-jpg-in-linux/) library then I make `shell_exec(convert $path $newPath)`, Then `Image::make($newPath)`and finally upload the image after converted it from the serve.